# Why is this string on the stack not exactly the one I entered?

Tags: disassembly, gdb, buffer-overflow

I was trying to understand buffer overflow attacks using the following C program

```
#include"stdio.h"  
#include"string.h"   
void iwontprint()  
{  
    printf("i wont be printed!");  
}  

void callme()  
{  
    char buffer[8];  
    gets(buffer);  
    puts(buffer);  
}  

int main(int argc,int** argv)  
{  
    callme();  
    return 0;  
}
```

Loading up the program in GDB before calling the `gets(buffer)` gives the following value of ESP :

```
0xbffff4d4: 0xb7ff0590 0x080484db 0xb7fc1ff4 0xbffff4e8  
0xbffff4e4: 0x080484b6 0xbffff568 0xb7e79e46 0x00000001
```

And after entering the input `123456789abc\x7c\x84\x04\x08` I am getting totally different values in ESP :

```
0xbffff4d4: 0xbffff4d8 0x34333231 0x38373635 0x63626139  
0xbffff4e4: 0x6337785c 0x3438785c 0x3430785c 0x3830785c
```

I've already set `randomize_va_space = 0`

```
$cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space   
0
```

Can anybody provide any pointers as to what am I missing here ?

Comment: Although very interesting I find it off topic, voting to close

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Stack is totally fine. Look more careful at the values:

`0x34333231 0x38373635 0x63626139 0x6337785c 0x3438785c 0x3430785c 0x3830785c`

which interpreted as an ascii string becomes this. literally:

`123456789abc\x7c\x84\x04\x08`

As you can see, it's exactly what you entered. And I mean by that, that for example `\x7c` is the String `"\x7c"` and not `"|"`. Use this technique to send the values properly:

`echo -e "123456789abc\x7c\x84\x04\x08" | ./yourbinary`

Comment: Thanks for your response. however I am not able to understand why 0x63626139  is there instead of 0x0804847c (which i entered as input in little endian).

Comment: AFAIK , 0xbffff4d8 & 0x34333231 are for char buffer[8] and 0x38373635 should be for value of EBP (old). Then the next value should be the one i entered (beyond 12 bytes) ?

Comment: No. You didn't enter `0x0804847c`. You entered `0x3830785c`, which is: `0x5c==\ `, `0x78==x`, `0x30==0`, `0x38==8` that is `\x08` as a string. not the byte value 0x08.

Comment: actually , echo won't interpret \x escapes either unless you specify -e switch

Comment: Only on Linux. The BSD Version doesn't know this option (http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/echo/)

Comment: @samuirai: the `bash` builtin `printf` would handle both cases. Admittedly then you still rely on `bash`, but not on `/bin/echo`. Also in many shells there is a builtin `echo` and if you ran `bash` on FreeBSD you should get the "GNU" options on `echo` through that.

Answer (score 4):

Samurai's answer is correct , but put more clearly , your mistake is that you enter the literal string

```
123456789abc\x7c\x84\x04\x08
```

where as what you probably want is something like:

```
perl -e 'print "123456789abc\x7c\x84\x04\x08"' | ./yourbinary
```

In the first case the `\x7c\x84\x04\x08` is just that, a 16 characters length string, where in the second case, the `\x` escape sequence is actually interpreted and `\x7c\x84\x04\x08` is printed as just 4 bytes.